# Find positive fractions so that $k_1+k_2+...+k_n+k_{n+1} \leq 1/2^n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm working on a proof in topology and the only thing left to do is some combinatorics (number theory?), which I've never had any exposure to.  I would appreciate any help I can get.

I'm attempting to choose positive fractions $k_1,k_2,...,k_n,k_{n+1}$ so that, $k_1 < 1/2^2, k_2 < 1/2^2, k_3 < 1/2^3, k_4 < 1/2^4,...,k_n < 1/2^n, k_{n+1} < 1/2^{n+1}$ and so that,

$k_1+k_2+...+k_n+k_{n+1}  \leq 1/2^n$.

P.S. Help with tagging if this isn't a number theory question.

EDIT: I need to define the sequence $k_1,k_2,...$ first.  I wish to define it so that each $k_i$ is small enough to ensure two properties;

(1) $k_1 < 1/2^2, k_2 < 1/2^2, k_3 < 1/2^3, k_4 < 1/2^4,...,k_n < 1/2^n, k_{n+1} < 1/2^{n+1}$

and

(2) For any $n \in \mathbb N$, $k_1+k_2+...+k_n+k_{n+1}  \leq 1/2^n$.

Comment: Do you want $k_1 < \frac{1}{2^2}$ or $k_1 < \frac{1}{2^1}$?

Comment: The way it is... But I looked at your answer last night and somehow it wasn't working for me.  I'm trying to recall why. Give me a couple minutes.

Comment: There is a problem with the way I'm communicating the problem.  In the proof I must choose the size of $k_1,k_2,...$ with recursion up front.  Then later I want to be able to say that for any $n \in \mathbb N$, $k_1+k_2+...+k_n+k_{n+1}  \leq 1/2^n$. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Not really. Could you include more details in your question?

Comment: I understand the confusion now.  I needed to define every $k_n$, not just the first $n+1$ of them.  See if my edit makes the problem clear.

Comment: No chance. You'll have $k_1<k_1+\dots+k_{n+1}<1/2^n$ for all $n$, i.e., $k_1\le 0$. You can easily do $k_{n+1}+k_{n+2}+\dots<1/2^n$ though and I suspect that it may be what you really need...

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible. Assume that such a sequence exists, and look at the series

$$ \sum_{j=1}^\infty k_j. $$

By assumption, the partial sum $0 \le \sum_{j=1}^n k_j \le 2^{-n}$. Let $n \to \infty$ to conclude that 
$$ \sum_{j=1}^\infty k_j = 0, $$
which implies that $k_j = 0$ for all $j$.